# When to create your own IEnumerable class

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

If you are using a collection `List<T>` or even arraylist within a class, why would you want to create your own enumeration class when you can just implement IEnumerable and return the enumerator. I see examples online where people create their own enumerable class and implement current, movenext etc...

Comment: The examples you find online may have been written before C# supported iterator blocks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you have a collection class you may not be just wrapping some other collection that is Enumerable and will return exactly what you should.

That said, I always prefer to use the yield keyword even for manually defining an enumerable.  Most examples of people defining current/move next simply don't know about yield or how to use it.  (I once implemented an enumerable class defining Current/Move next for that exact reason.)

Another case could be that the underlying collection is old and doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` but just `IEnumerable`.  If your collection is strongly typed you'll want to do more than just return their enumerator (at the very least it will be a `.Cast<T>()` call).

If you do have an underlying collection it may also be a collection of some private nested class (possibly some sort of custom key-value-pair) that you don't want to publicly expose.  This is a case where you may need to return a .Select call rather than just passing on the existing enumerator (but most likely wouldn't need to actually implement your own iterator).

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to iterate through the lines of a files and you do not want to load them all in memory. You could return an `IEnumerable<string>` that will read the next line on demand instead of loading everything into memory. I also prefer using `yield` for this type of situations just like @Servy mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that those examples are pre-generics?  I can see that if you weren't using generics you would then be forced to implement IEnumerable and implement it's methods.